# How do I integrate this expression?

Tags: calculus, integration

Need to find the following: $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 4}}{x^3} dx$$

So far, after using integration by parts, I've arrived at $\frac{-\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2x^2} + \frac12 \int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-4}} dx$. How to proceed from here?

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^3}dx=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^4}x\ dx$$

Set $\sqrt{x^2-4}=u\implies x^2-4=u^2\iff x\ dx=u\ du$

$$I=\int\dfrac{u^2}{(u^2+4)^2} du=\int\dfrac1{(u^2+4)} du-4\int\dfrac{du}{(u^2+4)^2}$$

For the second part set $u=2\tan\theta$

---

Alternatively, set  $x=2\sec\theta$

Comment: Why $ x^2-4=u^2\iff x\ dx=u\ du$?

Comment: @Vizuna, Differentiate both sides wrt $x$

Comment: @Vizuna, $2$ will cancel out from both sides.